# Defining a width for my label

Tags: css

How can I define a width for the label Quantity (see below)? I would like a CSS solution without defining a style on the span but directly on the label.

Something like:

```
span label[for=Quantity] 
{ 
    width: 200px;
}
```

But the above css doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: The CSS is working fine, it's just that setting width doesn't apply to inline `label` element. http://jsfiddle.net/rQpAr/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your adding **width** to an **inline** element they wont accept that.

```
span label[for=Quantity] 
{ 
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: I think `inline-block` would be better for the purpose of a `label`.

Answer (score 0):

using the inline-block is better because it doesn't force the remaining elements and/or controls to be drawn in a new line

```
.label {
  width:200px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make label a block element and set float to left so you can put other controls next to it

```
label {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
}
```